# How do you call functions in the body of a for loop in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have defined a list of files in a Makefile.

I need to copy those files, with their directory structure, to a new location.

I can't use `cp --parent` because the source files live in ../ (so .. will be a part of the dest path).

I've decided, then, to do one for loop that creates the dirs, then a second for loop that copies the files.  The problem, however, is that I can't seem to call `$(dir $$file)` in the body of the for loop.  I always get "./" as the result, rather than the actual dir name.  If I do something like `echo $(dir foo/bar)`, that works fine, but `echo $(dir $$file)` (when `$$file` is 'foo/bar') always returns './'.

I've tried other options like `$(shell basename $$file)`, but that also doesn't work.

I've tried defining a function and calling it in the body of the for, but that, too, doesn't work.

Here's a quick example Makefile:

```
FILES := foo/faz \
         bar/baz \
         gah/gaz

all:
    @for f in $(FILES); do \
      echo $(dir $$f); \
    done
```

I expect the output of this to be:

```
foo
bar
gah
```

but instead, I'm getting:

```
./
./
./
```

I'm open to other solutions if my method is not the best.  At the end of the day, I need to be able to copy all the $(FILES) that exist in ../ (so ../foo/bar, for example) to a new dir called $(NEWDIR) (so newdir/foo/bar, for example).

This only needs to work under Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f` is a shell variable here. The make function `dir` is called on the string `$f` (which the shell then interprets as a variable expansion).

If you use a shell loop, you need to use the shell's constructs to extract the directory part:

```
@set -e; for f in $(FILES); do \
      echo $$(dirname $$f); \
    done
```

Don't forget `set -e`, so that if there's an error during the copy, the make rule will fail.

You can also use a `foreach` function in make to generate a bunch of `cp` commands. It makes the makefile harder to debug though.

Comment: Thank you, Gilles.  I missed the subtlety of Jim's correct response.  I also wasn't aware of dir vs dirname, as the latter is not mentioned here: [gnu manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html).
Also, set -e is a great help.

Comment: @BrianK `dirname` wouldn't be mentioned in the make manual since it isn't a make feature: it's an external command. It's mentioned in its own manual (man pages, or the GNU coreutils manual (for the Linux version)).

Comment: Ahh, yes, because we're in a shell loop.  Makes sense.  Thanks again.